# Kotlin parse 2 type of field(string, object) like on Swift

Tags: kotlin

on IOS i have a code for parsing nested json. This json can contains string and object. It looks like this(Swift):

```
struct Place: Codable {
    let value: [Dependent]?
}

enum Dependent: Codable {
  case object(Place)
  case string(String)

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container =  try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let objectVal = try container.decode(Place.self)
            self = .object(objectVal)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let stringVal = try container.decode(String.self)
            self = .string(stringVal)
        }
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .object(let value):
            try container.encode(value)
        case .string(let value):
            try container.encode(value)
        }
    }
}
```

But its to hard understand how i can create the same parser for Kotlin, i did code like this:

```
data class Place(
    val value: List<Dependent>
)

sealed class Dependent {
    data class OBJECT(val value: Place): Dependent()
    data class STRING(val value: String): Dependent()
}
```

It doesnt work, i feel i missed something

UPD:
The josn looks like this:

```
{
   "value": [
      "123123123",
      {"value": ["123123", "123123", {"value":["123"]}, "123"]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin - Serialize JSON Array to multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449062/kotlin-serialize-json-array-to-multiple-classes)

Comment: can you put your json here .

Comment: @Mohmmaed-Amleh have added

Comment: @IvoBeckers im not sure